# Access property from different View controller's

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a property declared like this in one of my view controllers:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
```

How can I access this property from other view controllers? Keep in mind that I'm using storyboards, not programatically loading views.

I'm a bit new to this..thanks.

**Details**

My root view controller has a TableViewController embedded within it which contains the property. Then I have another view controller that is pushed from the root view controller. When this view is pushed I want [musicPlayer play] to be called, but right now it doesn't recognize musicPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the view controller with the musicPlayer property from your other controller. How you get that depends on how the two controllers are related. Is one presenting the other? Does one push to the other? Is one the child of the other? These different relationships require different way to access the other controller. You need to provide more information about your app structure for me to answer more fully.

**After Edit:**

Implement prepareForSegue so you can pass information to your presented view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    TriggerViewController *dvc = (TriggerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.tableViewReference = segue.sourceViewController.childViewControllers[0]
}
```

Here tableViewReference is a property in the controller where you're trying to access musicPlayer (tableViewReference should be of the class TriggerViewController). Then, in that class you can call play like this:

[tableViewReference.musicPlayer play];

Comment: The 2 view controllers are unrelated.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4, well, that makes it more difficult, but you still need to describe your structure for me to help any more.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid circular imports?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, Is that question directed to me or the OP?

Comment: @rdelmar My root view controller has a TableViewController embedded within it which contains the property. Then I have another view controller that is pushed from the root view controller. When this view is pushed I want [musicPlayer play] to be called, but right now it doesn't recognize musicPlayer.

Comment: What do you mean by, the root view controller has a table view controller embedded in it? Is it a child view controller? What class is your root view controller?  A navigation controller?

Comment: But the view is being pushed from the root view controller, not the TableViewController. So doesn't that mean they're unrelated?

Comment: I have a segue between the root view controller and the other view controller. I call performSegueWithIdentifier in the code.

Comment: I have a Container View in my root view controller. And it's connected to a TableViewController.

Comment: Ok, I think we're finally getting somewhere. So let me see if I understand. The one you're calling the root view controller is the root view controller of a navigation controller? And it has a table view controller embedded in a container view? You then push from the root view controller to the one where you want to access the property of the table view controller?

Comment: I edited your question to add some details. But you should say everything when asking questions, add everything is needed to get an answer.

Comment: That's correct, except I'm not using a navigation controller. Here's a screenshot of my storyboard: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8bvgi4rjfv395s/Storyboard.png?m

Comment: Ok, so you're doing a modal segue, not a push (pushes can only be done if a controller is embedded in a navigation controller). See my edited answer.

Comment: Ok so I added `@property (weak, nonatomic) TriggerViewController *tableViewReference` to the TriggerViewController and synthesized it. But xcode doesn't recognize tableviewReference in prepareforSegue.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4, you probably need to change the class of dvc to TriggerViewController and import its .h file. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok that part worked. Only thing it doesn't recognize now is `childViewControllers[0]`. Are you sure this is how to get access through a Container view?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4, Yes, I'm sure. Try logging segue.sourceViewController.childViewControllers and see what it gives you.

Comment: It gives an error "Property 'childViewControllers' not found on object of type 'id'"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22356/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-thisiscrazy4)

Answer (score 1):

Well one way is that you could #import the view controller into other view controllers and access the properties that way. For a storyboard you could use the controller's `prepareForSegue:` method between the parent and child views. In the child view try something like `childView *child = (childView *)segue.destinationViewController;`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. If I do something like [musicPlayer play] in a different view controller, it won't recognize musicPlayer.

Comment: since you're using storyboards, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method, see updated answer

Comment: when you `[musicPlayer play]` in the other controller, did you `alloc and init` the view controller? post more info about your code please

Comment: No I didn't. I'm calling [musicPlayer play] in the viewDidLoad function of the controller. The musicPlayer is being set in a settings view controller and then I want to call play on it whenever the other view appears.

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't have to access the musicPlayer property from your root view controller, but from your table view controller. So it will be something like this:

```
[rootViewController.containerView.tableViewController.musicPlayer play];
```

Comment: I get an error saying, Property 'tableViewController' not found on object of type 'rootViewController.'

Comment: Then you haven't explained well where is musicPlayer exactly. You said "My root view controller has a TableViewController embedded within it which contains the property", what do you mean by embedded? Where is that exactly?

Comment: The musicPlayer property is in the TableViewController. By embedded I mean I have a Container View in my root view controller. And the container view is connected to a TableViewController. This screenshot might help.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8bvgi4rjfv395s/Storyboard.png?m

Comment: Ok, in my edited answer I assumed that you used these variable names, which are pretty indicative, try to see if it works.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to access the container view. I thought I could do something like this but it doesn't work. `[rootViewController.childViewControllers[0].tableViewController.musicPlayer play];`